# How to resolve subquery return more than one value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Could somebody please help me how to achieve the following?

Table:

```
ID      NAME       ROLE
1       KONDA      LEAD
1       SATHI      CO-LEAD
1       JOHN       CO-LEAD
2       REDDY      LEAD
2       SURESH     CO-LEAD
3       PRASAD     LEAD
```

My output should look like

```
ID      LEAD       CO-LEAD_1       CO-LEAD_2
1       KONDA      SATHI           JOHN
2       REDDY      SURESH
3       PRASAD
```

Thanks Inadvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation with the help of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ROLE ORDER BY NAME) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'LEAD' THEN NAME END) AS LEAD,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'CO-LEAD' AND rn = 1 THEN NAME END) AS "CO-LEAD_1",
    MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'CO-LEAD' AND rn = 2 THEN NAME END) AS "CO-LEAD_2",
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

To create a view, use:

```sql
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ROLE ORDER BY NAME) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)
SELECT  -- same as above
```

Comment: Could you help me how to create a view in oracle with above query i want to create a view. Thanks Inadvance

Comment: Just inline the CTE in the bottom query and it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry could you please modify the above query to create a view. I did not get you actually, Thanks Inadvance